# Android Built-in Camera Interface wont return image and crashes on cancel

Tags: android, camera

I'd like to ask for your help concerning Android's built in Camera Interface

When i click capture, the screen captures(meaning it freezes)
But when i click ok, it hangs. It's suppose to go back to the main interface but it doesn't.
When i press cancel, it would force close.
the code is pretty long but this is my listener:

```
 @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int
 resultCode, Intent data) 
     {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode,
 resultCode, data);
      Double x = null;
      Toast.makeText(mContext, x.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             switch (requestCode) {
             case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:

                 image.setImageURI(uri);
                 break;

             }
         }
}
```

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intent to call the camera interface.

`Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CALL_CAMERA);`

```
`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent){
if(requestCode == CALL_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
{ 
        if(imageReturnedIntent.getAction() != null)
    {
                // display image received on the view
                Bundle newBundle = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                newBitmap = (Bitmap) newBundle.get("data");

                if(newBitmap != null) 
                {       
                        ImageView imageViewProfilePicture = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfilePicture);
                        imageViewProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                        imageViewProfilePicture.invalidate();
        }
    }
}}`
```

Comment: Thanks! permission to use this:)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The startActivityForResult() sub needs to be within the class. I placed mine inside my onclick which was inside my onCreate sub.
Thanks guys:D